# Java api reflections

Tags: java

Как используя `java.lang.reflect.Method` определить, является ли метод `protected`? 
Есть ли аналог метода `isDefault()` и можно ли каким-то образом просмотреть аттрибуты объекта?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам поможет сочетание из [Method.getModifiers()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#getModifiers--) и [Modifier.isProtected()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Modifier.html#isProtected-int-)

```
if (Modifier.isProtected(method.getModifiers())) {
    ...
}
```

[Соответствующий раздел документации.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodModifiers.html)